# How do you refer to more than one .css file in html?

Tags: html, css

I have a homepage.html and it refers to styles.css(makes a table). But I also want homepage.html to refer to styles12.css because in styles12.css I have the css for taps.

how would I refer to two .css files?

```
<title>Testing Css/HTML files</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Can I just make another `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style12.css" />`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, just add the second bit as you mentioned:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style12.css" />
```

Comment: does not work for me,
I need my own css file + bootstrap.

Answer (score 14):

you can also use `@import` inside other style sheets.

```
@import url("site.css");
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommended @import. 1.) older browsers don't understand it, 2.) @import rules can cause resources to not get downloaded in the order specified in IE (where you have 3 or more) (note IE has a built in limit of 31 (either way))

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just use multiple link elements.

Note, however, that it isn't very efficient and it is generally better to combine all your stylesheets into a single file.

Comment: Do you have references for this?

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html / http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#CombineExternalCSS

Comment: The server is having to stat, open, and transmit multiple files. There's a little bit of overhead in doing this. Browsers use keep-alive connections now so multiple files are sent over one network connection. Originally HTTP requests only fetched one file, so you had the overhead of establishing a connection for each file. In the days of HTTP 1.0 multiple files incurred large (by comparison) overhead. HTTP 1.1 and keep-alive greatly reduced it, but not completely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and the order of precedence for rules will follow the basic CSS precedence ruleset, and later rules overwrite earlier rules if they specify the same attributes.

You might want to read [this article on specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

Answer (score 1):

could you not just do

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text.class">
```

would this work for linking more than 1 css page for each web page

```
<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text.class>
```