# Adding multiple CSS file in HTML

Tags: html, css

Can we put multiple CSS files in a single HTML code using  tags in  section because in single CSS it is very complicated to write code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you refer to more than one .css file in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511048/how-do-you-refer-to-more-than-one-css-file-in-html)

Answer (score 4):

Yep! Very easy, simply link to each individual CSS file you want to use.

For example:

```
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hopefully this helps!